# Mongo Exception

Tags: mongodb, exception

I recently had some storage issues on my PC so I changed the mongo.conf file to reduce the size of the journal. These are the lines which I put in.

```
mmapv1:
    smallFiles: true
```

However, every time when I try to run mongo with the new changes I get this error(without the change it works just fine). Can you tell me what's the problem?

---

> 2016-02-11T22:32:14.002+0000 I FTDC     [ftdc] Unclean full-time diagnostic data capture shutdown detected, found interim file, some metrics may have been lost. OK
>
> 2016-02-11T22:32:14.023+0000 W FTDC     [ftdc] Uncaught exception in 'UnknownError Caught std::exception of type boost::filesystem::filesystem_error: boost::filesystem::file_size: No such file or directory: "/data/db/diagnostic.data/metrics.interim.temp"' in full-time diagnostic data capture subsystem. Shutting down the full-time diagnostic data capture subsystem.

Answer (score 28):

I would try deleting the directory `/data/db/diagnostic.data`.

You can also disable the diagnostic data collection by starting mongo with the option:

```
setParameter:
    diagnosticDataCollectionEnabled: false
```

Comment: Do you happen to know exactly what happens if I delete that directory? When installing I don't think I checked send diagnostics.

Comment: If you delete that directory it will get recreated. I would recommend that you only delete that directory while the server is stopped. Diagnostic data collection is enabled by default. It does not get "sent" anywhere, it's only collected locally.

Comment: Just for clarification, the `diagnostics.data` directory essentially contains a recording of periodic `db.serverStatus()` output, and it doesn't get sent anywhere. If you have a support agreement with MongoDB, you may be asked to upload the content of this directory for support/troubleshooting purposes.

Comment: How to set this in a docker compose file?

Comment: This works. Add "command” under the mongo container.  command: mongod --setParameter diagnosticDataCollectionEnabled=false

Answer (score 7):

I had the same problem after MongoDb failed when HD was fulled upto 100%. Here is the log:

```
2016-10-03T10:13:42.017+0000 I CONTROL  [initandlisten] MongoDB starting : pid=12630 port=27017 dbpath=/var/lib/mongo 64-bit host=drft006
2016-10-03T10:13:42.018+0000 I CONTROL  [initandlisten] db version v3.2.9
2016-10-03T10:13:42.018+0000 I CONTROL  [initandlisten] git version: 22ec9e93b40c85fc7cae7d56e7d6a02fd811088c
2016-10-03T10:13:42.018+0000 I CONTROL  [initandlisten] OpenSSL version: OpenSSL 1.0.1e-fips 11 Feb 2013
2016-10-03T10:13:42.018+0000 I CONTROL  [initandlisten] allocator: tcmalloc
2016-10-03T10:13:42.018+0000 I CONTROL  [initandlisten] modules: none
2016-10-03T10:13:42.018+0000 I CONTROL  [initandlisten] build environment:
2016-10-03T10:13:42.018+0000 I CONTROL  [initandlisten]     distmod: rhel62
2016-10-03T10:13:42.018+0000 I CONTROL  [initandlisten]     distarch: x86_64
2016-10-03T10:13:42.018+0000 I CONTROL  [initandlisten]     target_arch: x86_64
2016-10-03T10:13:42.018+0000 I CONTROL  [initandlisten] options: { config: "/etc/mongod.conf", net: { port: 27017, unixDomainSocket: { filePermissions: 511 } }, processManagement: { fork: true, pidFilePath: "/var/run/mongodb/mongod.pid" }, security: { authorization: "enabled" }, storage: { dbPath: "/var/lib/mongo", journal: { enabled: true } }, systemLog: { destination: "file", logAppend: true, path: "/var/log/mongodb/mongod.log" } }
2016-10-03T10:13:42.045+0000 I -        [initandlisten] Detected data files in /var/lib/mongo created by the 'wiredTiger' storage engine, so setting the active storage engine to 'wiredTiger'.
2016-10-03T10:13:42.045+0000 W -        [initandlisten] Detected unclean shutdown - /var/lib/mongo/mongod.lock is not empty.
2016-10-03T10:13:42.045+0000 W STORAGE  [initandlisten] Recovering data from the last clean checkpoint.
2016-10-03T10:13:42.045+0000 I STORAGE  [initandlisten] wiredtiger_open config: create,cache_size=93G,session_max=20000,eviction=(threads_max=4),config_base=false,statistics=(fast),log=(enabled=true,archive=true,path=journal,compressor=snappy),file_manager=(close_idle_time=100000),checkpoint=(wait=60,log_size=2GB),statistics_log=(wait=0),
2016-10-03T10:13:42.465+0000 I FTDC     [initandlisten] Initializing full-time diagnostic data capture with directory '/var/lib/mongo/diagnostic.data'
2016-10-03T10:13:42.465+0000 I NETWORK  [HostnameCanonicalizationWorker] Starting hostname canonicalization worker
2016-10-03T10:13:42.467+0000 I NETWORK  [initandlisten] waiting for connections on port 27017
2016-10-03T10:13:43.012+0000 I FTDC     [ftdc] Unclean full-time diagnostic data capture shutdown detected, found interim file, some metrics may have been lost. OK
2016-10-03T10:13:43.045+0000 W FTDC     [ftdc] Uncaught exception in 'UnknownError: Caught std::exception of type boost::filesystem::filesystem_error: boost::filesystem::file_size: No such file or directory: "/var/lib/mongo/diagnostic.data/metrics.interim.temp"' in full-time diagnostic data capture subsystem. Shutting down the full-time diagnostic data capture subsystem.
```

I `kill`-ed mongod and cleared the contents of the diagnostic folders:

```
> rm -f  /var/lib/mongo/diagnostic.data/*
```

After the restart of mongo log showed:

```
2016-10-03T10:17:46.745+0000 I CONTROL  [initandlisten] MongoDB starting : pid=12803 port=27017 dbpath=/var/lib/mongo 64-bit host=drft006
2016-10-03T10:17:46.745+0000 I CONTROL  [initandlisten] db version v3.2.9
2016-10-03T10:17:46.745+0000 I CONTROL  [initandlisten] git version: 22ec9e93b40c85fc7cae7d56e7d6a02fd811088c
2016-10-03T10:17:46.745+0000 I CONTROL  [initandlisten] OpenSSL version: OpenSSL 1.0.1e-fips 11 Feb 2013
2016-10-03T10:17:46.745+0000 I CONTROL  [initandlisten] allocator: tcmalloc
2016-10-03T10:17:46.745+0000 I CONTROL  [initandlisten] modules: none
2016-10-03T10:17:46.745+0000 I CONTROL  [initandlisten] build environment:
2016-10-03T10:17:46.745+0000 I CONTROL  [initandlisten]     distmod: rhel62
2016-10-03T10:17:46.745+0000 I CONTROL  [initandlisten]     distarch: x86_64
2016-10-03T10:17:46.745+0000 I CONTROL  [initandlisten]     target_arch: x86_64
2016-10-03T10:17:46.745+0000 I CONTROL  [initandlisten] options: { config: "/etc/mongod.conf", net: { port: 27017, unixDomainSocket: { filePermissions: 511 } }, processManagement: { fork: true, pidFilePath: "/var/run/mongodb/mongod.pid" }, security: { authorization: "enabled" }, storage: { dbPath: "/var/lib/mongo", journal: { enabled: true } }, systemLog: { destination: "file", logAppend: true, path: "/var/log/mongodb/mongod.log" } }
2016-10-03T10:17:46.772+0000 I -        [initandlisten] Detected data files in /var/lib/mongo created by the 'wiredTiger' storage engine, so setting the active storage engine to 'wiredTiger'.
2016-10-03T10:17:46.772+0000 W -        [initandlisten] Detected unclean shutdown - /var/lib/mongo/mongod.lock is not empty.
2016-10-03T10:17:46.772+0000 W STORAGE  [initandlisten] Recovering data from the last clean checkpoint.
2016-10-03T10:17:46.772+0000 I STORAGE  [initandlisten] wiredtiger_open config: create,cache_size=93G,session_max=20000,eviction=(threads_max=4),config_base=false,statistics=(fast),log=(enabled=true,archive=true,path=journal,compressor=snappy),file_manager=(close_idle_time=100000),checkpoint=(wait=60,log_size=2GB),statistics_log=(wait=0),
2016-10-03T10:17:47.128+0000 I FTDC     [initandlisten] Initializing full-time diagnostic data capture with directory '/var/lib/mongo/diagnostic.data'
2016-10-03T10:17:47.128+0000 I NETWORK  [HostnameCanonicalizationWorker] Starting hostname canonicalization worker
2016-10-03T10:17:47.129+0000 I NETWORK  [initandlisten] waiting for connections on port 27017
```

and mongo was ok.

Answer (score 2):

In case you are using nodejs, try to disable/remove debug mode in your server code.

Steps:

1. `rm -rf /{your_db_name}/diagnostic.data/`
2. remove or comment out `mongoose.set('debug', true);`
3. restart mongo and node server

Answer (score 1):

In my case I use docker-compose. First I **remove the diagnostic.data folder** from my mounted volume:

```bash
sudo rm -rf /srv/mongo/diagnostic.data
```

And then when I use **docker-compose up** the diagnostic.data folder will be re-created and everything was working again.

Comment: This works. Add "command” under the mongo container. command: mongod --setParameter diagnosticDataCollectionEnabled=false