# How to stop Meteor's constant rewriting of the metrics.inherim file (for MongoDB)

Tags: mongodb, meteor

When the **Meteor** app is running, it (or **MongoDB**) constantly rewrites the `metrics.interim` file from `.meteor/local/db/diagnostic.data`.
I believe, it does it for the diagnostic purposes.

But it causes my **Dropbox** to keep syncing it  continually.

I found a “sister”-topic here:  [Mongo Exception](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35351958/mongo-exception)

How to stop that rewriting? E.g., maybe there are some settings to start Meteor with?

Comment: Ignore that folder in the Dropbox settings, which means your database won't be synced? Or do the sensible thing and use [Git](https://git-scm.com/) instead of Dropbox, trust me it's worth the few hours of learning curve. I don't think this question has anything to do with Meteor...

Comment: @MichaelMason Thanks, but I believe there should be some config for Meteor's MongoDB when Meteor is started. PS: I use both Dropbox and Git (I find it to be the most reliable setup for me).

Comment: either way any time your modify the database via your app, not just the diagnostic data, Dropbox will resync. It is in theory possible to turn off diagnostic data if you think that'll help. You'd need to fork Meteor and run from a checkout. Relevant code is https://github.com/meteor/meteor/blob/devel/tools/runners/run-mongo.js#L40-L56 At a glance it looks like you can just add a new line to the args array as follows: ```'--setParameter', 'diagnosticDataCollectionEnabled=false'```

Comment: (I don't think that's a good idea though)