# why mongod service stop working randomly

Tags: mongodb, amazon-web-services, nosql

we are using monngo db to store no sql data which is installed on an aws Ubuntu instance

but it mongod service stop randomly and shows error log

Unclean full-time diagnostic data capture shutdown detected, found interim file, some metrics may have been lost. OK

memory and storage on the instance is alright no spikes detected

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Mongo Exception](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35351958/mongo-exception)

Comment: This sounds like the OOMKiller. Please see https://stackoverflow.com/questions/624857/finding-which-process-was-killed-by-linux-oom-killer and check if `mongod` was killed by it.

Comment: @KevinAdistambha i checked for OOMKILLER by dstat --top-oom

and its showing like

mongod 106
mongod 106 
mongod 106 
mongod 106 


is it mean it was killed due to OOM do you have any idea what to do to avoid it

Comment: Some things you could try: 1) I believe Ubuntu in AWS isn't configured with swap. Try activating swap on it, and see if the issue persists. 2) Monitor your required memory usage, so you know exactly how much RAM `mongod` requires during peak usage. Add the required RAM accordingly to your instance. In both cases, turning on swap is very important, since it may allow you to run with more of a leeway before the OOMkiller kicks in.