# Log file keeps crashing the Mongodb portion of my project

Tags: mongodb, crash, mean-stack, mean, linode

So currently I am hosting a MEAN stack project on Linode cloud.  Every few days the Mongodb side of my project seems to crash and the only way I can fix it is by logging into the project via WinSCP, deleting the mongod.log file and then rebooting the project.  This is however only a short-term solution.

So far I’ve changed the rotation of the log file from weekly to daily, in order to reduce the size of the log file, however that hasn’t worked.

So in the last crash it gave the message:

```
FileStreamFailed: Failed to write to interim file buffer for full-time diagnostic data capture: /var/lib/mongodb/diagnostic.data/metrics.interim.temp\nActual exception type: mongo::error_details::ExceptionForImpl<(mongo::ErrorCodes::Error)39, mongo::AssertionException>\n"
```

Comment: What do the logs, either `mongod` or from the OS, say about the process terminating? We can only guess right now as no troubleshooting information has been provided in the question

Comment: So I read through my log file.  One of them gave the message:          
"FileStreamFailed: Failed to write to interim file buffer for full-time diagnostic data capture: /var/lib/mongodb/diagnostic.data/metrics.interim.temp\nActual exception type: mongo::error_details::ExceptionForImpl<(mongo::ErrorCodes::Error)39, mongo::AssertionException>\n"}}"

Comment: Google suggests that error is related to your disk being full [reference](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35351958/mongo-exception). This would also match the stated behavior that deleting a log file allows you to restart the database. Perhaps you should look at clearing some more space on disk or moving the database elsewhere?

Comment: So I tried your recommendation.  It didn't really make any better.  In fact right now the server has totally crashes seconds after I rebooted it

Comment: I'm not sure how we are supposed to help without more information about the current situation or problem. Everything you've shared up to this point has suggested that the disk/directory that the database is using is full. If that's still the case (how big is the database, how much space is on the disk, etc) then that problem still needs to be addressed. If there is a different problem now then we'd those new details to advise differently. Also, log rotation often doesn't automatically delete the files, it just creates a new one but leaves the old one in place.